# StackExchange.Redis TIMEOUT growing unsent queue

Tags: stackexchange.redis

Our test environment last weekend saw a number VMs start logging timeouts where the unsent queue just kept growing:

> Timeout performing GET 0:B:ac64ebd0-3640-4b7b-a108-7fd36f294640, inst:
>   0, mgr: ExecuteSelect, queue: 35199, qu: 35199, qs: 0, qc: 0, wr: 0,
>   wq: 0, in: 0, ar: 0, IOCP: (Busy=2,Free=398,Min=4,Max=400), WORKER:
>   (Busy=5,Free=395,Min=4,Max=400)
>
> Timeout performing SETEX 0:B:pfed2b3f5-fbbf-4ed5-9a58-f1bd888f01,
>   inst: 0, mgr: ExecuteSelect, queue: 35193, qu: 35193, qs: 0, qc: 0,
>   wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 0, ar: 0, IOCP: (Busy=2,Free=398,Min=4,Max=400),
>   WORKER: (Busy=6,Free=394,Min=4,Max=400)

I've read quite a few posts on analyzing these but most of the time it doesn't involve the unsent message queue growing.  No connectivity errors were logged during this time; an AppPool recycle resolved the issue.  Has anyone else seen this issue before?

Some potentially relevant extra info:

1. Same timeouts seen on 1.0.450 and 1.0.481 versions of StackExchange.Redis nuget package
2. ASP.Net v4.5 Web API 1.x site was the one affected
3. Upgraded to Redis 3.0.4 (from 3.0.3) same week errors were encountered (but days prior)
4. Installed New Relic .NET APM v5.5.52.0 that includes some StackExchange.Redis instrumentation (https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/release-notes/agent-release-notes/net-release-notes/net-agent-55520), again, a couple days prior to the timeouts.  We've rolled this back here just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm encountering same issue.

To research issue, we logging ConnectionCounters of ConnectionMultiplexer for monitoring on every 10 seconds.

It shows growing pendingUnsentItems only, it means StackExchange.Redis does not send/receive from socket.

```
completedAsynchronously completedSynchronously  pendingUnsentItems  responsesAwaitingAsyncCompletion    sentItemsAwaitingResponse
1   10  4   0   0
1   10  28  0   0
1   10  36  0   0
1   10  51  0   0
1   10  65  0   0
1   10  72  0   0
1   10  85  0   0
1   10  104 0   0
1   10  126 0   0
1   10  149 0   0
1   10  169 0   0
1   10  190 0   0
1   10  207 0   0
1   10  230 0   0
1   10  277 0   0
1   10  296 0   0
...snip
1   10  19270   0   0
1   10  19281   0   0
1   10  19291   0   0
1   10  19302   0   0
1   10  19313   0   0
```

I guess socket writer thread was stopped?

My Environment is

- StackExchange.Redis 1.0.481
- Windows Server 2012 R2
- .NET Framework 4.5
- ASP.NET MVC 5.2.3
- Installed New Relic .NET APM v5.7.17.0

Comment: I haven't seen the issue re-occur in our test environment (or any other for that matter) since my original post after downgrading New Relic .NET Agent (in our case to v5.2).  Seems like that could be the common factor?

Comment: I rollback a version of New Relic(to 4.1.136, I use before an upgrade) in our production environment. This issue is not encountering afterwards. I reported this issue to New Relic support.

Comment: New Relic Agent 5.8 is fixed this issue but dropped measure of asynchronous operation(supports only sync operation) on dashboard.

Comment: Yep, New Relic Agent 5.8 seems to have resolved this for us as well -- sitting in test for a couple weeks now and we've not seen the issue again.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue was seen when using New Relic .NET APM between versions 5.5-5.7 and is fixed in 5.8.